# How does my score ranges change when I use class weight in Keras vs when I don't?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, class-imbalance, imbalanced-learn

Following are images of Unweighted Score Range and Weighted Score Range

[image: Un-Weighted Score Range]

[image: Class Weighted Score Range]

Comment: What is the scoring metric used?

Comment: This is the distribution of probability values of data point. Which scoring metric are you looking for ?